# AWS Lambda layer in eu-west-2 containing gdal & python-gdal bindings

Tags: gdal, osgeo, amazon-web-services, lambda

I need to write a Lambda that uses GDAL. I've tried using https://github.com/developmentseed/geolambda, but I need the layer from eu-west-2 region due to other dependencies. I've tried other Lambda layers but always end up getting the error as soon as I try to import gdal from osgeo as

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the exact error (as text)